# boundary analysis test case on string match algorithm

Tags: testing, analysis, boundary

In software testing, boundary value analysis is intuitive for numerical input, but when I try to do some boundary analysis on some string match algorithms (e.g boyer moore), I find it is hard to do the boundary analysis and derive some test cases for it.

for numerical boudary, e.g. x is the input and x>=100. The boundary value is 100
so for this example

```
boundary: x>=100
on point: x=100
off point: x=101
```

But then consider the string matching, I have two equivalent classes:

```
EC1: length(pattern) = length(text), pattern occurs in text.  
EC2: length(pattern) = length(text), pattern occurs not in text.
```

EC1 should return a match(which is 0), and EC2 should return -1.But the boundary values are hard to determine cos it is not a numerical boundary, so can I say:

```
boundary: pattern occurs in the text.
on point: pattern occurs in the text. 
off point: pattern does not occur in the text
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello! Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a look at [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips on asking good questions. Also, consider sharing your knowledge question-and-answer style by answering your own question.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've edited my question.

Comment: It is more clear now, but are you testing for equality between pattern and text?

Comment: yes, that's the case. but in other equivalence class, e.g length of the text is greater than the length of the pattern, I still need to determine the boundary value for this situation whether pattern occur in text or not.

Comment: So why don't you just test for equality? What exactly are you asking?

Comment: oh yes, you are right, equality is good for this case. thanks. how about this situation: length of the text is greater than the length of the pattern, I still need to determine the boundary value for this situation whether pattern occurs in the text or not.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about on-points and off-points and boundary values, at least with strings, because it gets confusing fast. Try using [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

Comment: yes, it is confusing...anyway thanks for your kindly help!